# gpg reverse encryption

Tags: gpg, pgp

I have sent an armored pgp encrypted message and since then have lost the original message. Being on the same system, the algorithms and keys used to encrypt the message should could also be reversed to decrypt the message back, right? I've tried `gpg --decrypt pgpmessage.txt` and `gpg --decrypt --recipient recipient pgpmessage.txt` and I still get errors. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

`gpg --encrypt` uses asymmetric encryption: it encrypts to one or more public key(s), and the result can only be decrypted using the corresponding private key. To decrypt your message, you need the private key of one of the recipients; unless you encrypted it to yourself, you probably won’t have this.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created a message that's also encrypted to yourself, you won't be able to decrypt it. In the future, you can use `--encrypt-to` or `--hidden-encrypt-to`. These options are intended for use with your own key ID, allowing you to additionally encrypt the message to yourself.

```
   --encrypt-to name
          Same  as --recipient but this one is intended for use in the op‐
          tions file and may be used with your own user-id as an "encrypt-
          to-self".  These keys are only used when there are other recipi‐
          ents given either by use of --recipient or by the asked user id.
          No  trust checking is performed for these user ids and even dis‐
          abled keys can be used.

   --hidden-encrypt-to name
          Same as --hidden-recipient but this one is intended for  use  in
          the options file and may be used with your own user-id as a hid‐
          den "encrypt-to-self". These keys are only used when  there  are
          other  recipients  given  either by use of --recipient or by the
          asked user id.  No trust checking is performed  for  these  user
          ids and even disabled keys can be used.
```

The reason you need to encrypt it to yourself using one of these options is due to how public key encryption works. To encrypt a message with a given public key, GnuPG will generate a random symmetric encryption key and use that to encrypt the message (ususally AES-CFB). The AES key is then padded and encrypted with a public key. If you want to have multiple recipients, the same key is encrypted again using a different public key and is appended to the message. Thus an encrypted message with multiple recipients has a single copy of the AES-encrypted message and then several copies of the AES key, each only decryptable by one recipient.

If you aren't one of those recipients, you can't decrypt the AES key, which means you can't decrypt the message. GnuPG does not store copies of the symmetric key it generated anywhere, so once it is used to encrypt the message and it itself is encrypted to each recipient, it is destroyed. You have no way of getting it back without access to the private key of a recipient.